# Empty response from PHP/mySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

i'm having problems with my php function but i can't figure out where! Someone can help me? The java class log me `Log: entry corrupt or truncated` and when i go parsing the json data returns `JSONException: End of input at character 0 of`.
From the debug i saw it return an empty string "".

This is the php code:

```
...
if ($tag == 'getFollowing') {
   // Request type is getFollowing
    $user_id = intval($_POST['user_id']);
     $following = $db->getFollowing($user_id);  
 if ($following) {
            //following get successfully
            $response['success'] = 1;
    $response['following'] = $following;
    echo json_encode($response);
     } else {
            // following failed
            $response['error'] = 1;
            $response['error_msg'] = 'Error occured in getting following';
            echo json_encode($response);
     }
} else {
    echo "Invalid Request";
}
...
?>
...
/**
 * returns followings
 */
public function getFollowing($follower_id) {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT followed_id FROM follows WHERE follower_id = '$follower_id'");

    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$return_arr = array($no_of_rows);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $followed_id = $row['followed_id'];
        $followed = getUserById($followed_id);
        array_push($return_arr, $followed);
    }
}
    return $return_arr;
}
```

and java code:

```
public List<JSONObject> getUserFollowing(String user_id) throws JSONException {
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", getFollowing_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id));
    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(followURL, params);

    JSONArray arrayUsers = (JSONArray) json.get("following");
    List<JSONObject> users = new ArrayList<JSONObject>(); 

    for (int i=0; i<arrayUsers.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jObj = arrayUsers.getJSONObject(i);
        users.add(jObj);
    }
    // return json
    return users;
}
```

the jsonParser and getUserById works perfectly with others functions. So where am i wrong?

Comment: How you set $tag? Also i see that if you don't have a result from db you will return array instead of false, so this check: if($following) will be always true

Comment: @bksi $tag == "getFollowing" so it open the if block. So, if it is always true, why it does not even set success=1 or following=an-empty-array ?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right. `intval` is not a substitute for proper escaping, it's a crutch.

Comment: I just say what i saw. You have to debug your code yourself. What PHP shows in browser with these params set? You could use browser development tools to see what the server returns. This will help you to find out where is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved in this way

```
 public function getFollowing($follower_id) {
    $return_arr = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follows WHERE follower_id = '$follower_id'");

    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $followed_id = $row['followed_id'];
            $followed = $this->getUserById($followed_id);
            array_push($return_arr, $followed);
        }
        return $return_arr;
    } else {
        // user not found
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem was that is necessary the $this call

```
$followed = $this->getUserById($followed_id);
```